# Is there a way to code a 4 day work and 2 day off work schedule in python with start date and end date

Tags: time, schedule

Currently self learning python and was thinking of coding myself a little exercise to learn on how to code a 4 day work and 2 day off work schedule in python with start date and end date. It should highlight or print only 4 days and skip next 2 dates and continue on this loop till it reaches specified end date. So far I am here in my code and cant go further. Any help in tutoring me on this exercise is appreciated.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

start_date = datetime.today()
end_date = int(28)
date_today = datetime.strftime(start_date, "%d")

convert_int = int(date_today)

for i in range(convert_int, end_date):
    print(i)
```